# Properly formatting JSON object in Swift 3

Tags: ios, json, node.js, swift, swift3

I'm having an issue getting my JSON object in a proper format on my server running Node.js. I have my API set up to receive a JSON object and store it in a database. This works great when I send it a POST request from postman (as shown below), but it throws an odd error when I send it from iOS. As an example:

[image]

The first json object shown is sent from postman. The second one is from iOS (using Swift 3). The error essentially crashes the server, saying:

```
AssertionError: Error: key          {"firstname":"testFirstName","lastname":"testLastName","email":"testemail123@gmail.com","username":"testusername123", == null
```

I'm not exactly sure why this is the case. I assume it has to do with the way the object is created? This is the swift code I'm using to create the object:

```
let infoDictionary = [
            "username":  UserNameField.text!,
            "password":  PasswordField.text!,
            "firstname": FirstNameField.text!,
            "lastname":  LastNameField.text!,
            "email":     EmailField.text!
        ]

        // Whole block = send above dictionary as JSON to server:
        if JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(infoDictionary) {
            do {
                let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: infoDictionary,
                                                            options: .prettyPrinted)
```

I then append that to the http body. Note that the fields are from text fields in the UI of the app that I unwrap and place into a dictionary. When I print it out as a string in swift, it comes out as the correct format, there is just something going wrong when I actually go to send it to my server.

EDIT: Per request the full URL request is below:

```
do {
                let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: infoDictionary,
                                                            options: .prettyPrinted)
                // Create Post request
                let url = URL(string: "websiteurl")
                var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
                request.httpMethod = "POST"

                // Append JSON object
                request.httpBody = jsonObject

                // Send request
                let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
                    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No Data")
                        return
                    }
                    let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                    if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {
                        print(responseJSON)
                    }
                }
                task.resume() // Sends the request
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could it be that you have to pass the infoDictionary to AlamoFire, and not the jsonObject?

Comment: I'm not using AlamoFire, making the HTTP request manually using URLRequest / URLSession. So I create the request using URLRequest, then add the json object to the body of that request.

Comment: Sorry!! I thought I had read "AlamoFire" somewhere – don't know why. But anyway: Apparently your jsonObject is wrapped into another JSON string. Please add the code how the URLRequest is created.

Comment: Just added the code I use to make the request!

Comment: That looks fine. Perhaps you have to set the http Content-Type to "application/json" ?

Comment: Try `request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-type")`

Comment: Yep that fixes it. Thank you guys so much! Is there a way I can select a comment as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request body is fine, it contains a valid JSON object, but
apparently the server interprets the HTTP body as *string* and wraps
it into another JSON object. Note that "text/plain" is the default
content type for HTTP requests (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-5.2).

The solution is to set the content type explicitly:

```
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-type")
```